# How to insert text after a certain string in file using run script in iOS

Tags: ios, bash, sed, podfile

We are trying to update the file using run scripts. We are using the command

```
 sed -i '/use_frameworks/a  HelloPod1'  ../Podfile
```

and building the application then we are getting error link this

> sed: 1: "../Podfile": invalid command code .
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

If we try to run the command from terminal its working fine.

`sed` command won't work in `Xcode` run scripts ? How can we insert the new lines in file ?

Comment: Try `sed -i.bak '/use_frameworks/a  HelloPod1'  ../Podfile`... `iOs`'s `sed` expects an argument after `-i`...

Answer (score 1):

`sed` on `iOs` expects a backup file suffix after `-i` option. Even when you think you haven't provided it, it will take next argument as suffix.

So, it takes `/use_frameworks/a  HelloPod1` as suffix and `../Podfile` as sed command. `../Podfile` is not a valid sed command, which causes the error.

This should work:

```
sed -i.bak '/use_frameworks/a HelloPod1' ../Podfile
```

Now, it takes `.bak` as backup suffix, `/use_frameworks/a  HelloPod1` as sed command and `../Podfile` as the file to operate on.